# Getting data from specific document ID in Firebase Firestore with Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm still very new to Firebase and I've been trying to figure out how to get the specific data of a specific document in Firebase whenever I click on it.

I would appreciate any help.

This is where my listview shows up with all the data i entered in my database.
[image: image1]

When I click on one of the field this window shows up with the info I need of each employee added.

[image: image2]

Here is my code for the database class:

```
class DataBaseService {
  final String uid;
  DataBaseService({this.uid});

  //collection reference
  final CollectionReference MyEmployees =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('employees');
  Future<void> updateEmployeeInfo(
    String firstName,
    String lastName,
    String profession,
    String status,
    String email,
    String phone,
    String birth,
    String address,
    String taxNumber,
    String major,
    double salary,
  ) async {
    return await MyEmployees.doc(uid).set(({
      "firstName": firstName,
      "lastName": lastName,
      "profession": profession,
      "status": status,
      "email": email,
      "phone": phone,
      "birth": birth,
      "address": address,
      "taxNumber": taxNumber,
      "major": major,
      "salary": salary,
    }));
  }

 
  // Get employees
  Future getEmployeesList() async {
    List itemList = [];

    try {
      await MyEmployees.get().then((querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.docs.forEach((element) {
          itemList.add(element.data());
        });
      });
      return itemList;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Database:

[image: Database]

Comment: Please add any error message you are getting. Is the issue with query or update? [Please try to improve your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to query specific user you will have to add `uid` to your user model.

```
Future<void> updateEmployeeInfo(
    String firstName,
    String lastName,
    String profession,
    String status,
    String email,
    String phone,
    String birth,
    String address,
    String taxNumber,
    String major,
    double salary,
  ) async {
    return await MyEmployees.doc(uid).set(({
      "uid": uid, //Add this line
      "firstName": firstName,
      "lastName": lastName,
      "profession": profession,
      "status": status,
      "email": email,
      "phone": phone,
      "birth": birth,
      "address": address,
      "taxNumber": taxNumber,
      "major": major,
      "salary": salary,
    }));
  }
```

And when you want to get that specific user you can query it like this:

```
await MyEmployees.doc(Employee.uid).get();
```

Assuming you have `Employee` class created that matches your Firestore collection

Comment: I followed your instructions, I also made an Employee class cause i didnt have one but I only get an 'Instance of 'Future<void>' when i try to get the data

Comment: and the uid i added in the database gets a nulll value for some reason

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/vjVHF5N

Comment: You have to make sure you are passing uid which is not null when you are writing to firestore. And when you are getting data you have to store it somewhere. For example: 
final jsonData = await MyEmployees.doc(Employee.uid).get();

Comment: I appreciate ur help alot but i need a bit more clarification please, how am i supposed to pass the uid so its not null?

Comment: And also how can i use the data (jsonData) to display in my screen?

Comment: Well obviously you are sending null so you have error in your code that you have not posted. 
You have to pare Json data to you employee object first. Study this documentation for more info  https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/json